# Bind textbox value with dynamic div's

Tags: javascript

I am trying to append / (Bind) textbox innerhtml value to the dynamic div which has the pagination. When I am trying append with textbox with the div I am getting an error.

There are two elements in my initial page First One is for no of pages and other one is for enter some text. If I enter number 2 so two div will appear dynamically. Then I enter the greeting text second text box. Text should appear in the first div and for the second div if i click the button in the bottom second div should be empty. Using Pure javascript (Vanila).

I am trying to get value from the textbox. But I was not able to bind with the p tag which was available dynamically.

Kindly help me.

```
var gettext_Title = document.getElementById('title_Text')
var getresult = gettext_Title.value;
//alert(result);
var inputElement = document.getElementById("inputAdd_page");
var totalCount = 0;
inputElement.addEventListener('blur', function() {
var count = this.value;
// Gaurd condition
// Only if it is a number
if (count && !isNaN(count)) {
fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var j = 0; j < count; ++j) {
  spancount = document.createElement('span');
  prevPage = document.createElement('div');
  navbutton = document.createElement('button');
  hTitle = document.createElement('p');
  preview_PageSize = document.getElementById('page');

  navpageBtn = document.getElementById('pageBtn');


  navbutton.className = "div_navig";
  navbutton.setAttribute('id', ['pag_navg' + totalCount]);
  navbutton.setAttribute('data-page', totalCount);
  navbutton.innerHTML = [1 + totalCount];
  navbutton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var el = e.target;
    var page = parseInt(el.getAttribute('data-page'), 10);
    var allPages = document.querySelectorAll('.preview_windowSize_element');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(allPages, function (pageElement) {
      pageElement.style.zIndex = 0;
      });

    var pageEl = document.querySelector('div[data-page="' + page + '"]');
    pageEl.style.zIndex = 10;
    });

  spancount.className = "spanCount";
  spancount.innerHTML = [1 + totalCount];

  hTitle.setAttribute('id', ['Title' + (totalCount)]);
  hTitle.className = "title_boundry";

  prevPage.className = "preview_windowSize_element";
  prevPage.setAttribute('id', ['page' + (totalCount)]);
  prevPage.setAttribute('data-page', totalCount);
  prevPage.appendChild(spancount);
  prevPage.appendChild(hTitle);
  navpageBtn.appendChild(navbutton);

  preview_PageSize.insertBefore(prevPage, preview_PageSize.childNodes[0]);

  totalCount++;
}

inputElement.value = "";
document.body.appendChild(fragment);
```

}
});

Here is the Jsfiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/aLv96L2o/)

Thanks in advance

Kindly help me

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you mean, try this:

main.js :

```
(function () {
    var inputTitle,
        inputElement,
        current,
        totalCount = 0;

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (e) {
        inputTitle = document.getElementById('title_Text');
        inputElement = document.getElementById("inputAdd_page");
        inputElement.addEventListener('blur', onInputElementBlur);
        inputTitle.addEventListener('blur', onInputTitleBlur);
    });

    function onInputTitleBlur(e) {
        if (!!current) {
            var title = current.querySelector('p');
            title.innerText = inputTitle.value;
            inputTitle.value = '';
        }
    }

    function onInputElementBlur() {
        var count = this.value;
        // Gaurd condition
        // Only if it is a number
        if (count && !isNaN(count)) {
            var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
            for (var j = 0; j < count; ++j) {
                var spancount = document.createElement('span');
                var prevPage = document.createElement('div');
                var navbutton = document.createElement('button');
                var hTitle = document.createElement('p');
                var preview_PageSize = document.getElementById('page');
                var navpageBtn = document.getElementById('pageBtn');

                navbutton.className = "div_navig";
                navbutton.setAttribute('id', 'pag_navg' + totalCount);
                navbutton.setAttribute('data-page', totalCount);
                navbutton.innerHTML = 1 + totalCount;
                navbutton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                    var el = e.target;
                    var page = parseInt(el.getAttribute('data-page'), 10);
                    var allPages = document.querySelectorAll('.preview_windowSize_element');
                    Array.prototype.forEach.call(allPages, function (pageElement) {
                        pageElement.style.zIndex = 0;
                    });

                    var pageEl = document.querySelector('div[data-page="' + page + '"]');
                    current = pageEl;
                    pageEl.style.zIndex = 10;
                });

                spancount.className = "spanCount";
                spancount.innerHTML = 1 + totalCount;

                hTitle.setAttribute('id', 'Title' + (totalCount));
                hTitle.className = "title_boundry";

                prevPage.className = "preview_windowSize_element";
                prevPage.setAttribute('id', 'page' + (totalCount));
                prevPage.setAttribute('data-page', totalCount);
                prevPage.appendChild(spancount);
                prevPage.appendChild(hTitle);
                navpageBtn.appendChild(navbutton);

                preview_PageSize.insertBefore(prevPage, preview_PageSize.childNodes[0]);

                totalCount++;
            }

            current = document.querySelector('div[data-page="0"]');

            inputElement.value = "";
            document.body.appendChild(fragment);
        }
    }
}());
```

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link id="myStyleSheet" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" class="form-control title_Textbox" id="title_Text" placeholder="Text">
<input type="text" class="form-control title_Textbox" id="inputAdd_page" placeholder="No Of Pages">
<div class="preview_windowSize" id="page"></div>
<div id="pageBtn" class="row pagination_btn"></div>
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css :

```
.div_navig {
    background: lightGrey;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.pagination_btn {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.spanCount {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0 10px 0 5px;
}

.preview_windowSize {
    margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.preview_windowSize_element {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: lightGrey;
    border: 1px solid rgb(155, 155, 155);
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 93.5%;
    height: 300px;
}

.title_boundry {
    border: 1px dotted #000;
    height: 40px;
}
```